# same record helper inheritance from two different sub-types

Tags: delphi, record, helper

Having a type declaration with two sub-types deriving from the same internal type, how can we have a different record helper for each sub-type?

Example:

```
type
  SingleA = Single;
  SingleB = Single;

  _SingleA = record helper for SingleA
    procedure DoThingsToA;  
  end;

  _SingleB = record helper for SingleB
    procedure DoThingsToB;  
  end;
```

if I declare a var of type SingleA, i always get the helper from type SingleB, i know this to be normal behaviour if we override the same internal type, but why does it happen with different types?

Any help much appreciated...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not declaring sub-types here. This code:

```
type
  SingleA = Single;
  SingleB = Single;
```

Is merely declaring **aliases**, not **types**.  As such, `SingleA` and `SingleB` are actually the same type `Single`.

This is explained here:

[Type Compatibility and Identity (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity_(Delphi))

> When one type identifier is declared using another type identifier, without qualification, they denote the same type. Thus, given the declarations:
>
> ```
> type
>   T1 = Integer;
>   T2 = T1;
>   T3 = Integer;
>   T4 = T2;
> ```
>
> `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, `T4`, and `Integer` all denote the same type. To create distinct types, repeat the word `type` in the declaration. For example:
>
> ```
> type TMyInteger = type Integer;
> ```
>
> creates a new type called `TMyInteger` which is not identical to `Integer`.

In effect, the `= type x` construct creates new type info for the type so that
`TypeInfo(SingleA) <> TypeInfo(SingleB)`.

In your original code, you are just declaring two aliases for the same type `Single`.

For any given type (and its aliases), you can [only have one type helper in scope](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi)), so in your original code the `record helper for SingleB` hides the `record helper for SingleA`.

By upgrading the aliases to their own types, you avoid this issue:

```
type
  SingleA = type Single;    
  SingleB = type Single;  <<-- the type keyword makes SingleB distinct from SingleA
```

Now you will have two distinct types, and your record helpers will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much Johan, you've made it crystal clear!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, when you declare

```
type
   SingleA = Single;
```

Delphi sees this as an alias rather than a derived type.

So it sees, in your case, SingleA, SingleB and Single as all being identical. (You can see this by declaring a function with parameter of type SingleA and attempting to pass a SingleB parameter to it).

So Following the rule that for any one type there can only be one helper, and helper for SingleB was the last defined then, as you comment, the behaviour is to be expected.

### Edit

You can also see this by stepping through your code and looking at parameter type of a variable of type SingleA or SingleB in local variable window, foe instance. You will see that it is always specified as type Single.